# Input element range type does not support change event in FireFox or Safari. What is the workaround

Tags: javascript, html

I have a slider element in my data viz app that I want to fire an event with slider drag completes. This solution uses the `change` event and works fine in Chrome.

```
this.slider.addEventListener('change', e => {
    // do something when slider changes
})
```

However, FireFox and Safari only support the `input` event so the above approach will not work. What is the best work around to simulate `change` event in FireFox and Safari.

Here is all the relevant JS code

```js
const slider = document.createElement('input')
slider.type = 'range'

slider.min = 10
slider.max = 20

document.body.appendChild(slider)

slider.addEventListener('change', e => {
  // do something when slider changes
  console.log("change");
})
```

Comment: According to MDN the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event#browser_compatibility) is supported in Firefox 1.0 and Safar 3.0 and above.

Comment: Nope. The slider is completely no functional in latest version of FireFox and Safari.

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: Firefox is showing me a change event in the same way as Chrome/Edge (Windows10). Could you put up enough code for us to see when you expect change to occur.

Comment: I've added all relevant code.

Comment: I have added console logging. I see no logging in FireFox or Safari. Latest versions of each browser.

Comment: Please post enough code so that we can try this for ourselves my tests show the change event occuring.

Comment: Logs "change" for me in Firefox 92.0 / MacOS.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a large app and this is one of dozens of small widgets. Not possible to remove from the app.

Comment: If you run the snippet in the very same Firefox you experienced the problem in, does it log?

Comment: This is easily the strangest bug I have encountered in a while. No console logging. The slider is simply disabled, not functional.

Answer (score 1):

False alarm. Solved. This is has nothing to do with the input/range element. I have one or more event handlers attached to the document that are consuming mouse events intended for the input/range element.